# Remove profile from user

Tags: oracle, users

How do I clear user's profile?
I found how I can drop the profile (also using CASCADE), but I want to keep the profile and just remove it from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users have a profile assigned. You can alter the user to have the default profile by:

```
ALTER USER username PROFILE DEFAULT;
```